# Recommended paint for outdoor cement patio

Tags: painting, paint, outdoor, patio, cement

[image]

In my back garden, I have a small cement pad. It used to have a shed on it, but the previous owner took it with them when they left. I've decided to turn it into a sort of patio, which is working well. My only complaint is the somewhat dreary appearance of the cement.

I'm looking to paint it. I was in the local supply store the other day, and they have a few options, none of which seem perfectly suited to this application. The options include:

- Masonry Paint, meant for outdoors and cement, but probably not being walked on
- Floor Paint, where materials include cement, but indoor use only
- Tile and Step Paint, which is for outdoors, includes brick + cement, but only comes in a single colour (dark red)

Does anyone have recommendations around what type of products would be best suited for this application, and how they should be applied?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a colored sealer instead of paint. It is available in several color options. Sherwin Williams is just one of the brands I searched. The sealer will penetrate the concrete so minor surface damage will be less noticeable.

Comment: It'll probably be less slippery, too. Concrete paint tends to be very thick so as to be durable, and this results in a glossy slick finish.